# How to get current date and time as a constant?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get the current date and time as a global constant variable when the app first load. Then use this constant variable to call GET method.

Is there a way to do this in JS?

I tried:

```
const time = moment().format("MMMM DD YYYY, hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Please try: `const appStartedAt = new Date();`. It should get the current date-time, I think. Please share if that works.

Comment: I ```console.log``` this variable in an onClick event and the value changes every time.

Comment: So, what is the problem with your code @KevinTruong ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli the variable changes every time I make an HTTP request

Comment: @KevinTruong every time you make an HTTP request through code (*`fetch`, `axios` etc*) ? or you reload the page ?

Comment: I made my HTTP request through Axios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your constant should be initialize at the loading of the page and not on the http request

you should store the value in a variable and not recall moment() when you perform your http request

```js
const time = moment().format("MMMM DD YYYY, hh:mm:ss");

function displayInitTime() {
  console.log(time);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<button onClick="displayInitTime()">click me</button>
```

Comment: Even though I declared at the very top but the variable still changes, but in my CodeSandBox it works so it must be wrong somewhere in my code. Thanks for your answer.